# How to use $emit in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs-directive, dom-events

```
<span class="tag-cross pointer" ng-click="Delete($index,selecteditemslist)">x</span>
```

This is my directive html. I have three delete functions, but when delete an item all three are getting deleted.

This is my delete function:

```
scope.Delete = function (index, selecteditemslist) {

    scope.selectedIndex = index;

    scope.$emit('removeOrg', {
        index: index
    });

    scope.$emit('removeRecipient', {
        index: index,
        type: 'orgs',
        selecteditemslist: selecteditemslist
    });
    scope.$emit('removeRecipient', {
        index: index,
        type: 'people',
        selecteditemslist: selecteditemslist
    });
};
```

This is my controller:

```
$scope.$on('removeRecipient', function (event, args) {
    $scope.index = args.index;
    $scope.selecteditemslist = args.selecteditemslist;
    console.info($scope.index);
    console.info($scope.selecteditemslist);
    $scope.type = args.type;
    switch ($scope.type) {
        case "orgs":
            $scope.RemoveRolesDetach('detachOrg', $scope.selecteditemslist);
            $scope.recipientsOrg.splice($scope.index, 1);
            $scope.displayOrgs.splice($scope.index, 1);
            $scope.recipientsOrgIdArr.splice($scope.index, 1);
            break;
        case "people":
            $scope.RemoveRolesDetach('detachUser', $scope.selecteditemslist);
            $scope.recipientsPeople.splice($scope.index, 1);
            $scope.displayPeople.splice($scope.index, 1);

            $scope.recipientsPeopleIdArr.splice($scope.index, 1);
            break;
    }

});
```

How to solve this? When I click an item that particular item only should get delete. Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: how is `Delete` called... can you check whether `Delete ` is called 3 times

Comment: delete was calling one time but in delete all three $emit was triggering , how can i restrict it

Comment: how many times `removeRecipient` is called